# Unexpected end of file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PSQLPATH=$1
USER=$2
if [ -z ${PSQLPATH} ]; then
   echo "incorrect path param"
   echo "Usage: $0 psqlpath username"
   exit 1
fi
if [ -z ${USER} ]; then
   echo "incorrect username param"
   echo "Usage: $0 psqlpath username"
   exit 1
fi
${PSQLPATH}/createdb -h localhost -U ${USER} highway2
${PSQLPATH}/psql -f createDatatable.sql -h localhost -d highway2 -U ${USER}
${PSQLPATH}/psql -f insertStatements.sql -h localhost -d highway2 -U ${USER}
echo "execute passed"
exit 0
```

When I am trying to execute it like ./script.sh I got an error line 19: unexpected end of file. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: From my experience with bash, this error occurs if you have some minor syntax problem.

Comment: I m trying to find it, but I cant

Comment: Are you working in Cygwin, by chance?

Comment: Yes! From Windows. But connected throw ssh to host with ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your line endings. When I run your script (under Cygwin), with no arguments given, I get your error if I have Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`). When I use Unix-style line endings, by eliminating the `\r`s, the script runs, complaining about my not having given the correct parameters.

Comment: You are genius! I am editing this code in sublime, so I gone to `View -> Line endings -> unix style`. Tnx you very much!